# Should I use onboard video to free up my GPU for tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm running into a lot of memory allocation problems whilst attempting to train a network. I have a GTX 1070 and I'm using conda to set up the environment. Currently my GPU is running my monitor so I'm wondering if using onboard graphics might help with my issues? Additionally, the error logs I was getting have suddenly changed to be slightly different and I have absolutely no idea what I changed to result in that but now I'm getting an output that looks like this:

```sh
$ python training_bpm_only.py 100 temp2
2019-11-27 15:22:46.586350: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
2019-11-27 15:22:49.251739: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2019-11-27 15:22:49.362166: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1070 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7465
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2019-11-27 15:22:49.362539: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2019-11-27 15:22:49.363666: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-11-27 15:22:49.364438: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX
2019-11-27 15:22:49.366368: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1070 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7465
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2019-11-27 15:22:49.366684: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dlopen_checker_stub.cc:25] GPU libraries are statically linked, skip dlopen check.
2019-11-27 15:22:49.367869: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-11-27 15:22:50.178519: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-11-27 15:22:50.178786: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]      0
2019-11-27 15:22:50.178932: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1178] 0:   N
2019-11-27 15:22:50.180129: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6382 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2019-11-27 15:22:51.852085: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_100.dll
2019-11-27 15:22:53.857910: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2019-11-27 15:22:55.126031: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/redzone_allocator.cc:312] Internal: Invoking ptxas not supported on Windows
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. This message will be only logged once.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.813409: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:419] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.91GiB (rounded to 2047868928).  Current allocation summary follows.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.813823: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (256):   Total Chunks: 31, Chunks in use: 30. 7.8KiB allocated for chunks. 7.5KiB in use in bin. 1.2KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.814212: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (512):   Total Chunks: 6, Chunks in use: 6. 3.0KiB allocated for chunks. 3.0KiB in use in bin. 3.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.814598: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (1024):  Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 1.3KiB allocated for chunks. 1.3KiB in use in bin. 1.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.814997: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (2048):  Total Chunks: 2, Chunks in use: 2. 7.0KiB allocated for chunks. 7.0KiB in use in bin. 6.8KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.815362: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (4096):  Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 4.0KiB allocated for chunks. 4.0KiB in use in bin. 3.4KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.815691: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (8192):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.816017: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (16384):         Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.816344: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (32768):         Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.816676: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (65536):         Total Chunks: 2, Chunks in use: 2. 144.0KiB allocated for chunks. 144.0KiB in use in bin. 144.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.817093: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (131072):        Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 143.8KiB allocated for chunks. 143.8KiB in use in bin. 72.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.817519: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (262144):        Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0. 388.5KiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.817843: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (524288):        Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.818163: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (1048576):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.818487: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (2097152):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.818834: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (4194304):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.819154: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (8388608):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.819475: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (16777216):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.819791: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (33554432):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.820108: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (67108864):      Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0. 95.62MiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.820447: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (134217728):     Total Chunks: 4, Chunks in use: 4. 880.42MiB allocated for chunks. 880.42MiB in use in bin. 828.38MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.820813: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:869] Bin (268435456):     Total Chunks: 5, Chunks in use: 4. 5.28GiB allocated for chunks. 3.84GiB in use in bin. 3.84GiB client-requested in use in bin.
2019-11-27 15:23:05.821159: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:885] Bin for 1.91GiB was 256.00MiB, Chunk State:
2019-11-27 15:23:05.821355: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:891]   Size: 1.44GiB | Requested Size: 488.25MiB | in_use: 0 | bin_num: 20, prev:   Size: 488.25MiB | Requested Size: 488.25MiB | in_use: 1 | bin_num: -1
2019-11-27 15:23:05.821712: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:898] Next region of size 6692228864
2019-11-27 15:23:05.821894: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E00000 next 1 of size 1280
2019-11-27 15:23:05.822089: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E00500 next 2 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.822280: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E00600 next 5 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.822471: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E00700 next 4 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.822660: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E00800 next 8 of size 512
2019-11-27 15:23:05.822889: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E00A00 next 15 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.823084: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E00B00 next 11 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.823279: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E00C00 next 14 of size 512
2019-11-27 15:23:05.823478: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E00E00 next 13 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.823674: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E00F00 next 16 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.823863: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E01000 next 17 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.824054: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E01100 next 18 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.824246: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E01200 next 19 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.824444: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E01300 next 20 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.824649: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E01400 next 3 of size 4096
2019-11-27 15:23:05.824871: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E02400 next 6 of size 3584
2019-11-27 15:23:05.825084: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E03200 next 21 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.825292: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E03300 next 9 of size 147200
2019-11-27 15:23:05.825510: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E27200 next 7 of size 73728
2019-11-27 15:23:05.825707: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E39200 next 22 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.825897: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000504E39300 next 23 of size 255983616
2019-11-27 15:23:05.826105: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000514259300 next 24 of size 512
2019-11-27 15:23:05.826301: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000514259500 next 25 of size 512
2019-11-27 15:23:05.826504: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000514259700 next 26 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.826685: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000514259800 next 27 of size 3584
2019-11-27 15:23:05.826879: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051425A600 next 28 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.827097: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051425A700 next 29 of size 73728
2019-11-27 15:23:05.827299: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051426C700 next 30 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.827493: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051426C800 next 32 of size 512
2019-11-27 15:23:05.827704: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051426CA00 next 33 of size 512
2019-11-27 15:23:05.827918: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051426CC00 next 34 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.828136: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051426CD00 next 35 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.828339: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051426CE00 next 36 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.828632: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051426CF00 next 37 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.828903: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051426D000 next 38 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.829156: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051426D100 next 39 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.829423: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051426D200 next 40 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.829678: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051426D300 next 41 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.829920: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051426D400 next 42 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.830131: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051426D500 next 43 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.830322: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] Free  at 000000051426D600 next 44 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.830544: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051426D700 next 45 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.830747: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051426D800 next 46 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.830942: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] Free  at 000000051426D900 next 69 of size 397824
2019-11-27 15:23:05.831138: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 00000005142CEB00 next 70 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.831332: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] Free  at 00000005142CEC00 next 48 of size 100266240
2019-11-27 15:23:05.831552: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051A26DD00 next 49 of size 256
2019-11-27 15:23:05.831748: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 000000051A26DE00 next 12 of size 155235328
2019-11-27 15:23:05.831952: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000523679200 next 10 of size 255983616
2019-11-27 15:23:05.832178: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000532A99200 next 31 of size 255983616
2019-11-27 15:23:05.832408: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000541EB9200 next 50 of size 1048707072
2019-11-27 15:23:05.832633: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 00000005806D9200 next 51 of size 2047868928
2019-11-27 15:23:05.832849: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 00000005FA7D9200 next 52 of size 511967232
2019-11-27 15:23:05.833057: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] InUse at 0000000619019200 next 53 of size 511967232
2019-11-27 15:23:05.833269: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:905] Free  at 0000000637859200 next 18446744073709551615 of size 1547549952
2019-11-27 15:23:05.833508: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:914]      Summary of in-use Chunks by size:
2019-11-27 15:23:05.833704: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 30 Chunks of size 256 totalling 7.5KiB
2019-11-27 15:23:05.833896: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 6 Chunks of size 512 totalling 3.0KiB
2019-11-27 15:23:05.834090: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 1 Chunks of size 1280 totalling 1.3KiB
2019-11-27 15:23:05.834281: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 2 Chunks of size 3584 totalling 7.0KiB
2019-11-27 15:23:05.834477: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 1 Chunks of size 4096 totalling 4.0KiB
2019-11-27 15:23:05.834664: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 2 Chunks of size 73728 totalling 144.0KiB
2019-11-27 15:23:05.834875: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 1 Chunks of size 147200 totalling 143.8KiB
2019-11-27 15:23:05.835081: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 1 Chunks of size 155235328 totalling 148.04MiB
2019-11-27 15:23:05.835283: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 3 Chunks of size 255983616 totalling 732.38MiB
2019-11-27 15:23:05.835490: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 2 Chunks of size 511967232 totalling 976.50MiB
2019-11-27 15:23:05.835688: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 1 Chunks of size 1048707072 totalling 1000.13MiB
2019-11-27 15:23:05.835888: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:917] 1 Chunks of size 2047868928 totalling 1.91GiB
2019-11-27 15:23:05.836080: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:921] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 4.70GiB
2019-11-27 15:23:05.836264: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:923] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 6692228864 memory_limit_: 6692228956 available bytes: 92 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 13384458240
2019-11-27 15:23:05.836621: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:929] Stats:
Limit:                  6692228956
InUse:                  5044014592
MaxInUse:               6324449792
NumAllocs:                     220
MaxAllocSize:           2659202560

2019-11-27 15:23:05.837111: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:424] ****_************************************************************************_______________________
2019-11-27 15:23:05.837429: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1622] OP_REQUIRES failed at pooling_ops_common.cc:309 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[256,64,252,124] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
2019-11-27 15:23:05.837922: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[256,64,252,124] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
         [[{{node MaxPoolGrad}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

Train for 500 steps
Epoch 1/100

  1/500 [..............................] - ETA: 2:04:47Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "training_bpm_only.py", line 84, in <module>
    run(*argv)
  File "training_bpm_only.py", line 70, in run
    model.fit(ds, epochs=int(epochs), steps_per_epoch=500)
  File "C:\Users\cainy\Anaconda3\envs\beatnet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 728, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\Users\cainy\Anaconda3\envs\beatnet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 324, in fit
    total_epochs=epochs)
  File "C:\Users\cainy\Anaconda3\envs\beatnet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 123, in run_one_epoch
    batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\cainy\Anaconda3\envs\beatnet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py", line 86, in execution_function
    distributed_function(input_fn))
  File "C:\Users\cainy\Anaconda3\envs\beatnet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 457, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\cainy\Anaconda3\envs\beatnet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 520, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\cainy\Anaconda3\envs\beatnet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1823, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\cainy\Anaconda3\envs\beatnet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1141, in _filtered_call
    self.captured_inputs)
  File "C:\Users\cainy\Anaconda3\envs\beatnet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1224, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
  File "C:\Users\cainy\Anaconda3\envs\beatnet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 511, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "C:\Users\cainy\Anaconda3\envs\beatnet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[256,64,252,124] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
         [[node MaxPoolGrad (defined at C:\Users\cainy\Anaconda3\envs\beatnet\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference_distributed_function_1122]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how complex the model is. The 1070 has 8gb of vram which should be enough for last-gen models. You're also running Windows so ~1 gb of vram goes towards that (even at idle).

As a general rule, your GPU should be used only for model training, as most model's barely fit into memory. 
You'll run into some bios config issues as most igp's turn off when a gpu is put in.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. My only concern was that it didn't seem to be able to use ANY vram at all from reading the error logs.